# How can I accomplish this in php using a single variable?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Ok , so I have a  `$unique_answer_title` contains multiple arrays. Below is what I get when I use `var_dump($unique_answer_title)`:

`array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "Immediate" [1]=> string(3) "Yes" [2]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" [3]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" } array(8) { [0]=> string(9) "Immediate" [1]=> string(3) "Yes" [2]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" [3]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" [4]=> string(9) "Immediate" [5]=> string(2) "No" [6]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" [7]=> string(111) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> NX<sup>P</sup> Workstation " } array(12) { [0]=> string(9) "Immediate" [1]=> string(3) "Yes" [2]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" [3]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" [4]=> string(9) "Immediate" [5]=> string(2) "No" [6]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" [7]=> string(111) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> NX<sup>P</sup> Workstation " [8]=> string(20) "Greater than 3 years" [9]=> string(3) "Yes" [10]=> string(42) "Have a representative contact me via email" [11]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" } array(18) { [0]=> string(9) "Immediate" [1]=> string(3) "Yes" [2]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" [3]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" [4]=> string(9) "Immediate" [5]=> string(2) "No" [6]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" [7]=> string(111) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> NX<sup>P</sup> Workstation " [8]=> string(20) "Greater than 3 years" [9]=> string(3) "Yes" [10]=> string(42) "Have a representative contact me via email" [11]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" [12]=> string(9) "Immediate" [13]=> string(2) "No" [14]=> string(15) "Send literature" [15]=> string(77) "Sign me up for more info on the Biomek 4000<sup>&#134;</sup>." [16]=> string(88) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> Assay Workstation" [17]=> string(72) "SPRIworks Library Construction <sup>&#94;&#94;</sup>" } array(22) { [0]=> string(9) "Immediate" [1]=> string(3) "Yes" [2]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" [3]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" [4]=> string(9) "Immediate" [5]=> string(2) "No" [6]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" [7]=> string(111) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> NX<sup>P</sup> Workstation " [8]=> string(20) "Greater than 3 years" [9]=> string(3) "Yes" [10]=> string(42) "Have a representative contact me via email" [11]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" [12]=> string(9) "Immediate" [13]=> string(2) "No" [14]=> string(15) "Send literature" [15]=> string(77) "Sign me up for more info on the Biomek 4000<sup>&#134;</sup>." [16]=> string(88) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> Assay Workstation" [17]=> string(72) "SPRIworks Library Construction <sup>&#94;&#94;</sup>" [18]=> string(9) "Immediate" [19]=> string(2) "No" [20]=> string(30) "Have a representative visit me" [21]=> string(77) "Sign me up for more info on the Biomek 4000<sup>&#134;</sup>." } array(26) { [0]=> string(9) "Immediate" [1]=> string(3) "Yes" [2]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" [3]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" [4]=> string(9) "Immediate" [5]=> string(2) "No" [6]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" [7]=> string(111) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> NX<sup>P</sup> Workstation " [8]=> string(20) "Greater than 3 years" [9]=> string(3) "Yes" [10]=> string(42) "Have a representative contact me via email" [11]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" [12]=> string(9) "Immediate" [13]=> string(2) "No" [14]=> string(15) "Send literature" [15]=> string(77) "Sign me up for more info on the Biomek 4000<sup>&#134;</sup>." [16]=> string(88) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> Assay Workstation" [17]=> string(72) "SPRIworks Library Construction <sup>&#94;&#94;</sup>" [18]=> string(9) "Immediate" [19]=> string(2) "No" [20]=> string(30) "Have a representative visit me" [21]=> string(77) "Sign me up for more info on the Biomek 4000<sup>&#134;</sup>." [22]=> string(9) "Immediate" [23]=> string(2) "No" [24]=> string(5) "Other" [25]=> string(88) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> Assay Workstation" }`

How can I combine all the elements of these arrays shown below into one numerical array?

`array_merge($unique_answer_title)` doesn't seem to work ... and the variable `$unique_answer_title` itself is not an array, it's a group of multiple arrays. How can I get the elements of all these individual arrays together into one big array?

Comment: Hmm, this question reminds me some other question, let me see...

Comment: Oh, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723700/how-can-i-merge-multiple-separate-arrays-that-are-not-included-in-an-array - I now stop downvoting your low quality questions and place close/deletion votes. You seem to like this help-vampire stuff so I directly flag you with the moderators.

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge the single arrays in a foreach loop.

```
$mergedArray = array();
foreach($unique_answer_title as $single){
  $mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $single);
}
```

Comment: $unique_answer_title contains many arrays in it , it's not an array itself ... why would you iterate over it ???

Comment: It doesnt work .. this is what I am getting Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\tms\_reports\lead_synopsis.php on line 730

Comment: Can you add the code where $unique_answer_title is defined? Was that a single var_dump call or the output of var_dump in a loop/multiple calls?

Comment: that was a single var_dump ... the arrays that you see in the question is the var_dump from $unique_answer_title

Comment: Can you var_dump($single)? Maybe add the portion of code where you are dumping this to the original post?

Comment: that is what I get tring(9) "Immediate"
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\tms\_reports\lead_synopsis.php on line 730
string(3) "Yes"
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\tms\_reports\lead_synopsis.php on line 730
string(29) "Have a representative call me"